# Rails (rake) Data Import Concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, import, concurrency, rake

I am trying to migrate from a rails based service to another framework. I am trying to export my data from rails using rake tasks and import into the new schema.

Right now my rake tasks do all of the column mappings, which work fine. For example Customers in the rails app are now Accounts in the new application.

The problem is that my tasks take hours to complete. Essentially I do `User.find_each` -> then `Transaction.find_each` and so on. Each of these tables has tens of thousands of records.

I did my first pass at optimization and removed as many db calls as I could. I am utilizing redis where I can as well. It seems like to me I have gotten to a point where I need the tasks to run concurrently.

I looked into using the [parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) gem. The example in the documentation is the following:

```
Parallel.each(User.all, in_processes: 8) do |user|
  user.update_attribute(:some_attribute, some_value)
end
User.connection.reconnect!
```

I am worried I can't use that because when I call `Customer.all` my vm freezes because I can't keep them all in memory (hence the `find_each`).

I guess my question is it possible to use the parallel gem with `find_each`? I cannot find anything in their documentation or examples online doing such. Is there another solution I can do to for iterating over the Customers concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question,

> is it possible to use the parallel gem with find_each? I cannot find anything in their documentation or examples online doing such. Is there another solution I can do to for iterating over the Customers concurrently?

I would recommend you to use [`find_in_batches`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) by Activerecord. You can query for a batch of records and then iterate over each element in the batch using Parallel. For example, it can be something like

```rb
User.find_in_batches do |batch|
  Parallel.each(batch,in_processes: 8) do |user|
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: How can I verify that these processes are running in parallel?

Comment: For the parallel processes scenario, the gem creates new child processes using [fork](https://github.com/grosser/parallel/blob/master/lib/parallel.rb#L444) command. Hence, you should be able to see child processes for the process started by you. (I use `htop` or `ps` to check this in a linux based system)